# JSON response with jQuery - what is the correct way to handle?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

When using the `$.ajax` call in JQuery, what is the correct way to get the variables in this JSON feed:

```
{"response": [ {"code":"2", "responseText":"No comments added."}]}
```

Typically, I use the `$.each` to loop through the various elements of the JSON response, but when there is only one item with sub items, I just figured it would be something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost/comments.php",
        data: "userID=" + user_id + "&start=0",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
        alert(data.response.code); //2
        }
});
```

However I am getting an undefined variable when I attempt this. This seems so easy, however I am really struggling. Any tips or pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Since the result is an array of objects, you need to first get the object from the array, and then access the properties of that object.

```
data.response[0].code
```

should work.